# jQuery: toggle a <div> to it's original position as stated on the divs ID in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I have several divs with the class "itemWerk". I wish to toggle them, so that i can enlarge them and set them back to the original size and position.

I've come quite far as you can see over [here](http://casperjonker.site50.net/MijnWerk.html). It's just the positioning in my second function i can't get to work. I'm not really sure what i should use: .position or .offSet or .data... Seen several guides that sort of explain what i'm looking for but can't get it to work.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.itemWerk').toggle(

function(){

    $(this)
        .animate({'z-index':'10'}, { duration: 0, queue: false })
        .animate({'left':'0.5em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'top':'0.5em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'width':'74em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'height': '53em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })

    $("#achtergrondWerk")
        .animate({'height':'54em'},{ duration: 400, queue: false }) 
;},

function(){

    $(this)
        .animate({'left':'postion.left'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'top':'position.top'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'width':'10em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'height': '16em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })

    $("#achtergrondWerk")
        .animate({'height':'38em'},{ duration: 400, queue: false }) 
});
```

Here is one of the divs in the HTML document:

```
<div class="itemWerk" id="werkEen">



</div>
```

And here is the CSS code for the class .itemWerk

```
.itemWerk {
width: 10em;
height: 16em;
background: white;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

and the ID #werkEen

```
#werkEen {
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: During my testing I saw that jQuery 1.8.3 and 1.9.0 treat `toggle` differently. 1.9.0 apparently deprecates the function/function implementation. It is now exclusively for hiding/showing content. The toggle executes immediately and causes all your divs to collapse on load. If you upgrade your jQuery and notice your page breaks now you will know why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `animate()` uses `style` attribute. So you can do this:

```
$('.itemWerk').removeAttr('style');
```

Yeah, I was about to say those from the comments.

> **Note:** The [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) project extends the `.animate()` method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.

An example with [CSS Class Animation using jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/), without using inline styles.

---

If you wanna just rely on jQuery and `.animate()` method, you can use `.data()` to have the previous values stored.

```
$('.itemWerk').toggle(

function(){

    $.data(this, 'top', $(this).css('top'));
    $.data(this, 'left', $(this).css('left'));
    /* if you need to store others, yeah, go ahead **/

    $(this)
        .animate({'z-index':'10'}, { duration: 0, queue: false })
        .animate({'left':'0.5em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'top':'0.5em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'width':'74em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'height': '53em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })

    $("#achtergrondWerk")
        .animate({'height':'54em'},{ duration: 400, queue: false }) 
;},

function(){

    $(this)
        // use the $.data this way: //
        .animate({'left':$.data(this, 'left')}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'top':$.data(this, 'top'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'width':'10em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'height': '16em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })

    $("#achtergrondWerk")
        .animate({'height':'38em'},{ duration: 400, queue: false }) 
});
```

#### Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/K2PL3/

Comment: This'll just snap it back to the original position without an animation.

Comment: i am afraid he wants to animate it back to previous position

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Using jQuery UI solves the problem. Check the updated answer. :)

Comment: Yup, kind of. But removing `style` attribute will **NOT** cause abrupt change in position now. :)

Comment: ps: The OP **needs to do some work**. We are not here to spoonfeed. Rather, I have surely guided him a different approach, which I am using and working. Didn't I?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - It sure will.

Comment: Will tweak the code and give a solution too, if that is what is necessary. I thought the OP will be able to work on his own.

Comment: Well first of all thanks a lot for the rapid reactions and all. I think I'll be able to work from this, definitly a different approach. As long as it'll work i'll be smiling.

Comment: @Yonker I see that you just need to reset the styles. I am giving an answer, that works. Behold for a moment. :)

Comment: @Yonker To have previous data, you can use `.data()` this way: `$.data(this, 'z-index', $(this).css('z-index'));`

Comment: @Yonker Can you please check the answer for an updated approach that works?

Comment: I don't think the css values top and left will work in this case. The elements start as `inline-block` and do not have top or left specified. The animation process sets them to `absolute`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Yes, it does work. I didn't realize that top and left, even when not specified, will default to the offset values from their parent. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding in the past 9 hours. When i asked the question it was almost 5 o clock in the night and i was really stuck. Everything works with the .data()! Perfectly. Thanks a lot Praveen Kumar.

Comment: By the way, if anyone wants to use this: The fiddle made by Praveen does it all. All you have to do is set the background of .itemWerk to a random color so you can see the div.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Sorry, sort of new to Stackoverflow, accepted it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` to store the top and left position of the elements. Then use those values when you animate the item back into place.

http://jsfiddle.net/AKhGc/

You can choose `offset` or `position` for retrieving the top and left values. You want `position` because you are looking for relative to the parent.

```
$('.itemWerk').toggle(

function () {
    //store itemWerk's original size and position
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('left', $this.position().left).data('top', $this.position().top);

    //animation code removed because it isn't relevant to the answer

},

function () {
    $this = $(this);

    $(this)
        .animate({'left':$this.data('left')}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'top':$this.data('top')}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'width':'10em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({'height': '16em'}, { duration: 400, queue: false })

    $("#achtergrondWerk")
        .animate({'height':'38em'},{ duration: 400, queue: false }) 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for putting your time and effort in this.